# Problem with CreateDC and wglMakeCurrent

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, gdi

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { /* otherwise fine for a window with 32-bit color */ };

HDC hDC = CreateDC(TEXT("Display"),NULL,NULL,NULL); // always OK

int ipf = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pfd); // always OK

SetPixelFormat(hDC,ipf,&pfd); // always OK

HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC); // always OK

wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC); // ! read error: 0xbaadf039 (debug, obviously)
```

But the following works with the same hRC:

```
wglMakeCurrent(hSomeWindowDC,hRC);
```

The above is part of an OpenGL 3.0+ initialization system for Windows.
I am trying to avoid creating a dummy window for the sake of aesthetics.
I have never used CreateDC before, so perhaps I've missed something.
edit: hSomeWindowDC would point to a window DC with an appropriate pixel format.
More info:
I wish to create a window-independent OpenGL rendering context.
Due to the answer selected, it seems I need to use a dummy window (not really a big deal, just a handle to pass around all the same).
Why I would want to do this: Since it is possible to use the same rendering context for multiple windows with the same pixel format in the same thread, it is possible to create a rendering context (really, just a container for gl-related objects) that is independent of a particular window. In this way, one can create a clean separation between the graphics and UI initializations.
The purpose of the context initially isn't for rendering (although I believe one could render into textures using it). If one wanted to change the contents of a buffer within a particular context, the desired context object itself would just need to be made current (since it's carrying the dummy window around with it, this is possible). Rendering into a window is simple: As implied by the above, the window's DC only needs to have the same pixel format. Simply make the rendering context and the window's DC current, and render.
Please note that, at the time of this writing, this idea is still in testing. I will update this post should this change (or if I can remember :P ).

Comment: `0xbaadf039` looks awfully close to `0xbaadf00d` -- which debuggers often fill uninitialized space with to make it obvious that they're not supposed to be used yet.

Comment: Yep, hence the quip about debug right next to it. The weird part is that I haven't done anything to the handles, nor performed any allocations beforehand.

Comment: What does GetLastError return? And why can't you just use a normal window?

Comment: The read error is a run time exception. I didn't intend for the original block to be interpreted as a single segment of source. I have edited it in a way that should more clearly emphasize the second part was a separate example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a dormant brain cell from reading Petzold 15 years ago that just sprang back to life.  The DC from CreateDC() is restricted.  Good for getting info about the display device, measurement, that sort of stuff.  Not good to use as a regular painting DC.  You almost certainly need GetDC().

Comment: Thank you! Of all the obscure things the Windows "universal object handle" paradigm leaves undocumented -- one is led to believe that any DC would work for this purpose.

Comment: Can you mention the section of that book where you found this? I'm asking because I just opened that book after reading your answer and it looks very close to what'd be the description of [CreateIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd183505(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which is mentioned in the same section as CreateDC, i.e. "Getting a device context handle".

Answer (score 1):

My current OpenGL 3+ initialization routine doesn't require a dummy window. You can simply attempt to make a second RC and make it current using the DC of the real window. Take a look at the OpenGL wiki [Tutorial: OpenGL 3.1 The First Triangle (C++/Win)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C%2B%2B/Win%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I am trying to create a context system that doesn't attach itself to a window, as this leads to a much cleaner initialization sequence (primarily an effort to further separate graphics from the UI itself). However, I have found that wiki to be a valuable documentation many times.

Comment: OK. Is that possible? If you come up with a solution could you update your question with it? I'd be very interested in it.

Comment: My question has been updated with an explanation of the solution.

Comment: Only thing is you can't create a multisample window this way, instead need to use multisample FBOs and resolve from FBO to the window.